# sign xml file with xmlsec1 in ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I´m trying to sing my file XML with `xmlsec1` in ubuntu. I has builded a script in `bash` that to do this operation.

My bash code it´s:

```
#!/bin/bash
value="${HOME}/demo.p12"
PATH2="${HOME}/installation_signed.xml"
PATH3="${HOME}/installation.xml"
PASS="logalty"
/usr/bin/xmlsec1 --sign --output $PATH3 --pkcs12 $value --pwd $PASS $PATH2
```

xmlsec1 now it´s running, but shell it´s returnning this message:

```
func=xmlSecOpenSSLAppPkcs12LoadBIO:file=app.c:line=776:obj=unknown:subj=PKCS12_parse:error=4:crypto library function failed:openssl error: 50856204: digital envelope routines: NULL unsupported
func=xmlSecOpenSSLAppKeyLoadBIO:file=app.c:line=358:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecOpenSSLAppPkcs12LoadBIO:error=1:xmlsec library function failed: 

func=xmlSecOpenSSLAppKeyLoad:file=app.c:line=217:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecOpenSSLAppKeyLoadBIO:error=1:xmlsec library function failed:filename=/home/pruebas-123456/demo.p12

Error: xmlSecCryptoAppKeyLoad failed: filename=/home/pruebas-123456/demo.p12

Error: failed to load pkcs12 key from "/home/pruebas-123456/demo.p12".

Error: keys manager creation failed

Unknown command

Usage: xmlsec <command> [<options>] [<files>]



xmlsec is a command line tool for signing, verifying, encrypting and

decrypting XML documents. The allowed <command> values are:

  --help        display this help information and exit
  --help-all    display help information for all commands/options and exit
  --help-<cmd>  display help information for command <cmd> and exit
  --version     print version information and exit
  --keys        keys XML file manipulation
  --sign        sign data and output XML document
  --verify      verify signed document
  --sign-tmpl   create and sign dynamicaly generated signature template
  --encrypt     encrypt data and output XML document
  --decrypt     decrypt data from XML document


Report bugs to http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/bugs.html
Written by Aleksey Sanin <aleksey@aleksey.com>.
Copyright (C) 2002-2016 Aleksey Sanin <aleksey@aleksey.com>. All Rights Reserved..
This is free software: see the source for copying information.
```

I think. My script not found my digital certificate, but in my home it´s my certificate:

[image]

Anybody can help me to solve this problem with bash script?.

**UPDATE 2**
I executed this command: `openssl pkcs12 -in demo.p12 -noout -info` i set my pass and return this message:

```
Enter Import Password:
MAC: sha1, Iteration 1024
MAC length: 20, salt length: 20
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 1024
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 1024
Error outputting keys and certificates
40770D7F287F0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:../crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:349:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()
```

i searched in web this message: `error outputting keys and certificates pkcs12` and i founded that i nedd add to command this parameter `-legacy` with this parameter my command it´s:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in demo.p12 -noout -info -legacy
```

And his return it´s:

```
MAC: sha1, Iteration 1024
MAC length: 20, salt length: 20
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 1024
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 1024
Certificate bag
```

**SOLUTION**

To solve my problem, first, in response to @dave_thompson_085 i try to execute this command, but return that my digital certificate was legacy. I have searching in google and i founded this forum:

https://github.com/lsh123/xmlsec/issues/309 in last response, this person say that we need edit file configuration to set default mode legacy. Edited my file and i trayed and work ok, now i have to solve my problem with my file xml, that return any warning when i tray sing my file xml. Thanks for help and i hope that my information can help to anybody.

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Comment: This is not a scripting problem, it's about using a program not in software development, which is (now) offtopic. And there's no problem 'finding'; xmlsec1 (not shell) is finding your demo.p12 but failing to _parse_ it. This could be something actually wrong in the file, or it could be an incompatibility -- PKCS12 has _lots_ of options. Try `openssl pkcs12 -in demo.p12 -noout -info` and give the password and see what output or errors it gives. Also which Ubuntu and which package versions do you have?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you very much for your help and response. I updated my question in update 2 but i don´t know very well that i need to do

Comment: Please don't post the same problem multiple times

Comment: @NicoHaase i´m sorry, but my problem, now it´s other although similiar. Now i can execute xmlsec1 but i don´t know wht it´s my problem to sign my xml

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 My version xmlsec1 it´s 1.2.38-1 and my ubuntu it´s 22.04

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 i solve my problem. In my question i wrote my solution